# creating a Spring RCP MDI application where to start?

Tags: java, spring, swing, jide, spring-rcp

I'm trying to build on top of Spring RCP (1.1.0 and trunk) and JIDE Software (demo version at the moment) with Maven, and got them compiling fine. I would like to build a MDI application but I haven't been able to find any directions on how to do so. Inspecting Spring RCP `core` code I can find the package `org.springframework.richclient.application.mdi` and some classes like `DesktopApplicationPage` but no idea how they should be used within the framework architecture.

The examples are all SDI, i.e. they have a top Window and include by default an internal view which can not be resized, closed or minimized. Furthermore, the application lifecycle has a `startingPageId` property that specifies the initial view and can be left empty but then I don't know where the plumbing goes for the classes under `org.springframework.richclient.application.mdi`. There is really zero Javadoc and no documentation on this anywhere.

UPDATE: actually while looking in the forums I realized that there is a fork of Spring RCP (which is apparently a dead project) and the fork is currently maintained as [Valkyrie RCP](https://github.com/cmadsen/Valkyrie-RCP) but there as well no documentation on how to do MDI.